# Swift Enumeration method call from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, swift4

My Swift enumeration is as below:

```
 @objc enum NetworkError: Int, RawRepresentable {
        case NoData
        case Generic

        func description() -> String {
            switch self {
            case .NoData: return "No data available"
            case .Generic: return "Something goes wrong, please try again later"
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, how to call the description method from my Objective-C class. In Swift the call is as simple as:

```
NetworkError.Generic.description()
NetworkError.NoData.description()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this.  If you look at the generated header the enum looks something like this to Objective-C:

```
typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, NetworkError) {
  NetworkErrorNoData = 0,
  NetworkErrorGeneric = 1,
};
```

It's just a basic C style enum, it's not an object with methods, more info https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22